# swift - creating a tableview like instagram's profile page

Tags: uitableview, swift

I have a tableview in my project. It lists the items in the inventory of the user. Now I want to add a new cell at the top and put some user info like profile picture and user name. Under this cell, user items will be listed. 
I tried to use sections, but I got errors.

Thanks,

Comment: Show us what you have tried and what errors are you getting.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a UICollectionViewController instead.

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewController_clas/index.html

You could then create a custom UICollectionViewCell that spans the width of your screen for the 'header'. Your items will flow onto the subsequent rows under the 'header'.

Answer (score 0):

This code is used for customization of the tableview section header:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    var myCustomView: UIImageView
    var myImage: UIImage = UIImage(named: "myImageResource")
    myCustomView.image = myImage

    let header: UITableViewHeaderFooterView = view as UITableViewHeaderFooterView
    header.addSubview(myCustomView)
    return header
}
```

Comment: https://blog.twitter.com/2014/a-new-profile-experience-on-twitter-for-iphone  twitter ios profile page a lot closer to what I want to do. tweets are tableview. Above the tweets tableview view, is that a header? I tried to add an uiview above my cell, but I couldnt connet uiview and other items (uiimageview&uilabe) to my tableviewcell...